# Converting a nested JSON into a flatten one and then to pandas dataframe using pd.json_normalize()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the below JSON as a dataframe. The below JSON is in a `string`.

```
 json_str='{"TileName": "Master",
  "Report Details": 
     [
       {
        "r1name": "Primary",
        "r1link": "link1",
        "report Accessible": ["operations", "Sales"]
       },
       {
       "r2name": "Secondry",
       "r2link": "link2",
       "report Accessible": ["operations", "Sales"]
       }
     ]
  }'
```

So I am trying to get below `df`

```
TileName      ReportAccssible     ReportName     ReportLink
Master        operations           Primary        link1
Master        Sales                Primary        link1
Master        operations           Secondary      link2
Master        Sales                Secondary      link2
```

In order to achieve the above, I am trying the below code snippet:

```
js_str = json.loads(json_str)
df = pd.json_normalize(js_df,'Report Details',['TileName',['report Accessible']],\
record_prefix='Col_',errors='ignore')
```

But the above code is not giving me the output as per desired format.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Is there wrong in the column `ReportLink`? I guess you want 'link1' and 'link2' instead of 'r1link' and 'r2link'.

Comment: yes. Spot on!! I have modified the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong [`record_path`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas.json_normalize), which should be `['Report Details', 'report Accessible']`.

```py
js_obj = json.loads(json_str.replace('r2', 'r1'))  # keep columns consistent
df = pd.json_normalize(js_obj, ['Report Details', 'report Accessible'], 
                       ['TileName', ['Report Details', 'r1name'], ['Report Details', 'r1link']])
df.columns = ['ReportAccssible', 'TileName', 'ReportName', 'ReportLink']
```

You will get what you want.

```
  ReportAccssible TileName ReportName ReportLink
0      operations   Master    Primary      link1
1           Sales   Master    Primary      link1
2      operations   Master   Secondry      link2
3           Sales   Master   Secondry      link2
```